# Deep Space cannons: how many times can they shoot?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

In Twilight Imperium 3rd ed you may get a technology advance that lets your PDS fire to a system adjacent to the one that contains them: The Deep Space Cannons.

The rules of firing in their same system stand but there is one extra scenario not described in the rules:

- If the enemy is at distance 2 and moves to an adjacent system, **passing through an adjacent system**  will the PDS fire once or twice? (Meaning, will they fire once the enemy enters the first adjacent system and once more once the enemy reaches the destination adjacent system?)

Of course, what if the enemy is moving to the system that contains the PDS, would they shoot twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not claiming an authoritative answer, but when playing recently the rule we followed is the activation rule -- the adjacent PDS may fire into a system that has been *activated*. So, in your scenario, the PDS would fire only one time.

From the TI3 Rule book (page 29):

> When a player activates a system in range of an
>   enemy PDS unit, the owners of any enemy PDS units
>   in range may, after the movement step of the
>   Activation Sequence, fire once per PDS at any units
>   in the system owned by the activating player. Note
>   that when firing your PDS units during another player's
>   activation, you may only fire at the units controlled 
>   by the activating player. It is thus not possible
>   to draw third party PDS fire at an enemy fleet by simply 
>   activating its system from afar.

Although I haven't sussed this out with my gaming group, I imagine a transfer action would invoke two opportunities for an adjacent PDS if the system holding the PDS is adjacent to both transfer-action-activated systems.